# Why the client.listen in fbchat cannot work again?

Tags: python, chatbot

I wan to make a chatbot that will automatically reply . it will collect reply from client.listen and then decide the reply to the user.

```
from fbchat import log, Client

# Subclass fbchat.Client and override required methods
class EchoBot(Client):
   def onMessage(self, author_id, message_object, thread_id, thread_type, **kwargs):
       self.markAsDelivered(thread_id, message_object.uid)
       self.markAsRead(thread_id)

       log.info("{} from {} in {}".format(message_object, thread_id, thread_type.name))

       # If you're not the author, echo
       if author_id != self.uid:
           self.send(message_object, thread_id=thread_id, thread_type=thread_type)


client = EchoBot("myaccount", "mypassword")
client.listen()
```

It worked fine until today.
Even it receive the message.the program still will stuck in client.listen

The output that i receive is this
Logging in myAccount...
Login of myAccount successful.
Listening...

When i try to contact my account , it still wont give me reply but it just stuck in client.listen
the output i wan to get is it will collect info from client.listen() and give me reply.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that facebook has changed the structure of the website (id's, classes...) where fbchat library was scraping data from (Keep in mind that **fbchat is not an official facebook library**). This can happen with any API that is not official. I have hosted my bot 24/7 and all of sudden it stopped working. Your code is perfectly correct. From what I have tested so far I can tell that EchoBot class stopped working with all of it's event listeners, but at the other hand you can still send messages with `client.send(...)` We can only hope that developers of fbchat library will fix this soon.
See here for more info: https://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat/issues/483

**2020 UPDATE**

The issue was fixed in new version of fbchat 1.9.6.

Just update the module with:

```
pip install fbchat --upgrade
```

Comment: I have found a fork of fbchat called fbchat-asyncio, you will have to change your code a little bit, but it workst the same check here https://github.com/tulir/fbchat-asyncio/ . From my personal experience, I have reworked my own chatting bot to this fork and it works.